# How to suppress compiler errors within vctmp.cshtml files in Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, model-view-controller, razor, visual-studio-2019

Whenever I open a temporary cshtml file or compare the difference between the files, the compiler shows a bunch of errors. It's unable to resolve razor syntax due to a lack of context:
[image]

My project does build despite these errors and I don't really care about errors in temporary files, but they are distracting and real errors get lost in the list. Is there any way to suppress or hide them specifically for the temp files?

Answer (score 0):

You may have an error in the html file name or not created. Model error is because you didn't send a model for view. Read carefully the errors already present in all information error screen.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I'm not sure how explain it exactly but that's not the issue. The file has no errors when opened normally. It's only when I open it, for example, to compare with the previous version of the file, that the errors show up. Or when I view the previous state of the file in older commits.